# Drupal 7 reverse node reference url effect

Tags: reference, drupal-7, nodes

I love using the [Node Reference URL](http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url) module but in the case of my current project I need something similar and with a slightly different effect.

I have a node type called **Event** which needs to have exactly 3 webforms referenced to each event I create.
With node_reference_url the configuration means I will setup the node reference fields in the webform node type with my Event type selected as the target.

**However, I need to find a way of reversing that. I'm looking for code tips (*or a module if it exists*) which will allow me to configure the Event type so that I can have links on each event page to create a total of 3 webforms and their NIDs to be saved as references to the parent event page.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to do such a thing. It allows you to add one or more reference fields to your content types. These references can be to nodes, profiles, etc.
If you would add these to your **Event** you could probably select the webforms from there.

I know this plugin also integrates with views (under advanced > relations), allowing you access the fields of the referred content. (Incuding the title and link to node options.)

*Want to take it a step further?*

Have a look at [reference dialog](http://drupal.org/project/references_dialog). This module allows you to build similar reference fields combined with Add, Edit and Delete buttons. If the content you are referring to is not yet created, you can do so in an overlay.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying reference dialog and it seems to be just what I need.